# how to extend default search to include the data of plugin?

Tags: wordpress

i want to carry out the search in my custom plugin table .i.e. when i search for some keyword or phrase, it should search in my custom table too.

And if the data is from my custom table then it should carry out my plugin function to display data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't know whether it was a good solution or not but i did it by myself. See below :

1. i added search.php to my default theme
2. after the if condition of have_posts and before else part mean in
   between i inserted my code

   elseif (pdfsearch_result($_GET['s'])):
           $search_pdf = mysearch_result($_GET['s']); // my search function to search for my plugin data

and then did formatting and achieved the desired result. Hope this may help someone, but do post if there is better way of doing this.